Mysqldump to Clickhouse failing constantly
So, I have a task assigned to me that is, on paper, pretty easy.  To take the data from our MySQL source of truth and import it into Clickhouse for analytics, for dates ranging from 11/21/24 to current.
The first issue is that each day in this table has > 2 billion rows in it. So I thought the best solution would be to do a MySQLDump that goes over it in chunks, and by day.
#!/bin/bash

# Configurable retries and wait time
RETRY_COUNT=3
RETRY_WAIT=10
MAX_ROWS=500000  # Number of rows to process per batch

# Start time tracking
start_time=$(date +%s)

# Database Config
MYSQL_BIN=$(which mysql)
MYSQLDUMP_BIN=$(which mysqldump)
MYSQL_CONFIG="/root/.my.cnf-prod-main-ro"
SOURCEDIR="/root/source_files"
SOURCE_DATABASE=""
SOURCE_TABLE="parking_visits_summary"
TARGET_DATABASE=""
TARGET_TABLE="parking_visits_summary_working"
TARGET_IP=$(cat "$SOURCEDIR/.clickhouse_ip")
TARGET_USER=$(cat "$SOURCEDIR/.target_user")
TARGET_PWD=$(cat "$SOURCEDIR/.target_password")
lock_file="/tmp/sync_${TARGET_TABLE}.lock"

mkdir -p /var/log/jobs/
EXECUTION_LOG_FILE="/var/log/jobs/sync_${TARGET_TABLE}_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').log"
exec > >(tee -a "$EXECUTION_LOG_FILE") 2>&1

# Fetch the last processed datetime
get_last_processed_date() {
    local query="SELECT MAX(server_datetime) FROM ${TARGET_DATABASE}.${TARGET_TABLE}"
    local last_datetime=$(clickhouse-client --host="$TARGET_IP" --secure --port=9440 --user="$TARGET_USER" --password="$TARGET_PWD" \
        --query="$query" 2>>"$EXECUTION_LOG_FILE")

    if [ -z "$last_datetime" ] || [ "$last_datetime" == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ] || [ "$last_datetime" == "1970-01-01 00:00:00" ]; then
        echo "2024-11-21"
    else
        echo $(date -d "$(echo "$last_datetime" | cut -d' ' -f1) +1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
    fi
}

# Get total rows for a specific day
get_total_rows_for_day() {
    local date="$1"
    $MYSQL_BIN --defaults-file="$MYSQL_CONFIG" --batch --raw --skip-column-names \
        --execute="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${SOURCE_TABLE} WHERE server_datetime BETWEEN '${date} 00:00:00' AND '${date} 23:59:59';" \
        "$SOURCE_DATABASE"
}

# Export and Stream Data for a Specific Day
export_and_stream_to_clickhouse() {
    local date="$1"
    local total_rows="$2"
    local offset=0
    local retry_attempts=0

    echo "Total amount of source rows for ${date}: ${total_rows}"

    while [ "$offset" -lt "$total_rows" ]; do
        echo "Processing rows for $date. Offset: $offset, Remaining: $((total_rows - offset))."

        $MYSQLDUMP_BIN --defaults-file="$MYSQL_CONFIG" --no-create-info --skip-triggers --quick --compact --set-gtid-purged=OFF \
            --where="server_datetime BETWEEN '${date} 00:00:00' AND '${date} 23:59:59' ORDER BY server_datetime LIMIT $MAX_ROWS OFFSET $offset" \
            "$SOURCE_DATABASE" "$SOURCE_TABLE" \
            | grep '^INSERT INTO' \
            | sed "s/),(/\n/g; s/INSERT INTO .* VALUES (//g; s/);//g" \
            | awk -F'\t' '{
                actual_nf = NF;  # Capture actual field count
                for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                    gsub(/"/, "\"\"", $i);  # Escape double quotes
                    if ($i ~ /\t|"/) $i = "\"" $i "\"";  # Wrap problematic fields in double quotes
                    if ($i == "NULL" || $i == "") $i = "\\N";  # Replace NULL with ClickHouse NULL representation
                }
                # Validate number of fields
                if (NF == 36) {  # Adjust to match your schema
                    OFS = "\t";
                    print
                } else {
                    print "ERROR: Malformed row (expected 36, got " actual_nf "): " $0 > "/tmp/row_errors.log"
                }
            }' > /tmp/processed_data.tsv

        if [ ! -s /tmp/processed_data.tsv ]; then
            echo "No valid rows to insert for $date. Skipping."
            return 1
        fi

        clickhouse-client --host="$TARGET_IP" --secure --port=9440 --user="$TARGET_USER" --password="$TARGET_PWD" \
            --query="INSERT INTO ${TARGET_DATABASE}.${TARGET_TABLE} FORMAT TSV" < /tmp/processed_data.tsv

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Successfully inserted rows for $date. Remaining: $((total_rows - offset - MAX_ROWS))"
            offset=$((offset + MAX_ROWS))
        else
            retry_attempts=$((retry_attempts + 1))
            if [ "$retry_attempts" -ge "$RETRY_COUNT" ]; then
                echo "Failed to insert data for $date after $RETRY_COUNT retries."
                return 1
            fi
            echo "Retrying in $RETRY_WAIT seconds..."
            sleep "$RETRY_WAIT"
        fi
    done
    return 0
}

# Main sync logic
sync_stage2() {
    local start_date=$(get_last_processed_date)
    local end_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

    echo "Starting processing from date: $start_date"

    while [ "$(date -d "$start_date" +%Y-%m-%d)" \< "$(date -d "$end_date + 1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)" ]; do
        echo "Processing data for $start_date..."
        local total_rows=$(get_total_rows_for_day "$start_date")
        if [ "$total_rows" -gt 0 ]; then
            if export_and_stream_to_clickhouse "$start_date" "$total_rows"; then
                echo "Successfully processed $start_date."
            else
                echo "Failed to process $start_date."
            fi
        else
            echo "No rows to process for $start_date."
        fi
        start_date=$(date -d "$start_date +1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
    done
}

sync_table() {
    sync_stage2
    end_time=$(date +%s)
    execution_time=$((end_time - start_time))
    echo "Sync completed in $(($execution_time / 3600))h $(($execution_time % 3600 / 60))m $(($execution_time % 60))s."
}

# Locking mechanism
exec 200>"$lock_file" || exit 1

if flock -n 200; then
    sync_table
    flock -u 200
else
    echo "Another sync process is already running."
    exit 1
fi

Is the code, and I put the debugging in there due to it failing to import anything at all into CH.
Here's the describe of the source MySQL table:
| Field               | Type               |
|---------------------|--------------------|
| id                  | varchar(36)        |
| uuid                | varchar(36)        |
| type                | varchar(100)       |
| server_datetime     | datetime           |
| domain_name         | varchar(80)        |
| ip_address          | int unsigned       |
| user_id             | mediumint unsigned |
| reportable          | tinyint unsigned   |
| country_id          | smallint unsigned  |
| page_query          | text               |
| page_url            | text               |
| full_domain_name    | varchar(300)       |
| ip_ip2_id           | bigint unsigned    |
| page_referer        | text               |
| og_referer          | text               |
| user_agent          | text               |
| channel             | varchar(500)       |
| zc_partner_id       | smallint unsigned  |
| zc_winner_bid       | decimal(16,4)      |
| subid_1             | varchar(500)       |
| subid_2             | varchar(500)       |
| subid_3             | varchar(500)       |
| subid_4             | varchar(500)       |
| subid_5             | varchar(500)       |
| ref_adnetwork       | text               |
| ref_keyword         | text               |
| ref_pubsite         | text               |
| google_id           | varchar(80)        |
| reportable_channel  | varchar(80)        |
| reportable_style_id | varchar(80)        |
| template_id         | int                |
| google_client_id    | varchar(80)        |
| terms               | text               |
| term_positions      | text               |
| parking_visits_id   | bigint unsigned    |
| created_at          | datetime           |

And the desc for the clickhouse working table:
| Field               | Type             |
|---------------------|------------------|
| id                  | String           |
| uuid                | String           |
| type                | String           |
| server_datetime     | DateTime         |
| domain_name         | String           |
| ip_address          | Nullable(UInt32) |
| user_id             | UInt32           |
| reportable          | Nullable(UInt8)  |
| country_id          | Nullable(UInt32) |
| page_query          | Nullable(String) |
| page_url            | Nullable(String) |
| full_domain_name    | Nullable(String) |
| ip_ip2_id           | Nullable(UInt64) |
| page_referer        | Nullable(String) |
| og_referer          | Nullable(String) |
| user_agent          | Nullable(String) |
| channel             | Nullable(String) |
| zc_partner_id       | Nullable(UInt64) |
| zc_winner_bid       | Nullable(String) |
| subid_1             | Nullable(String) |
| subid_2             | Nullable(String) |
| subid_3             | Nullable(String) |
| subid_4             | Nullable(String) |
| subid_5             | Nullable(String) |
| ref_adnetwork       | Nullable(String) |
| ref_keyword         | Nullable(String) |
| ref_pubsite         | Nullable(String) |
| google_id           | Nullable(String) |
| reportable_channel  | Nullable(String) |
| reportable_style_id | Nullable(String) |
| template_id         | Nullable(UInt32) |
| google_client_id    | Nullable(String) |
| terms               | Nullable(String) |
| term_positions      | Nullable(String) |
| parking_visits_id   | UInt64           |
| created_at          | DateTime         |

The issue is, the results are exporting fully wrong, and when I run a calculation of the columns, it's only showing up in 1 column, and failing the day.
[2024/12/18 22:03:13] Starting processing from date: 2024-11-21
[2024/12/18 22:03:13] Processing data for 2024-11-21...
[2024/12/18 22:03:30] Total amount of source rows for 2024-11-21: 23720882
[2024/12/18 22:03:30] Processing rows for 2024-11-21. Offset: 0, Remaining: 23720882.
[2024/12/18 22:04:01] No valid rows to insert for 2024-11-21. Skipping.
[2024/12/18 22:04:01] Failed to process 2024-11-21.

Then in the row_errors.log I get ALL of the data, all with the prepended error:
ERROR: Malformed row (expected 36, got 1)

I can't post the data that I get from here, as it has PII in it.
I'm still fairly new to this, so any assistance would be appreciated.

So, does the issue occur at exporting the data from mysql (question has nothing to do with clickhouse) or does it happen during the import (nothing to do with mysql)?

@Shadow The messages from the script are in the question (I fixed the formatting so you can see it better), so you can judge yourself.

Have you checked row_errors.log to see if the awk script is rejecting all the lines?

There's no good reason to use grep and sed before awk, it can do both those steps itself and makes debugging harder.

@Barmar I'm sorry, but those messages are meaningless to any of us as we do not know how many rows there are supposed to be and the OP wrote that the export is all wrong.

Thanks for the input all! The row_errors.log has EVERY row of the 100,000 (or whatever I set as the max_rows) - it is all coming out incorrectly. It is exporting right, and the transformations are going through, but it is resulting in junk data that will not import.

I would first try to dump a few rows, see works or not, as it is easier to debug in this case.

I'll put the exact error when I get to work tomorrow for absolute clarification. Apologies for not putting it in there before

@jsc0218 It doesn't matter how many rows I put in there for the max_rows, it all just goes to the row_errors.log as junk.

@Shadow The only errors I am getting are the ones I posted in the post, along with the error in the row_errors.log just saying ERROR: Malformed row (expected 36, got 1) and the exporting the CSV data

Your script for transferring data from MySQL to ClickHouse is quite comprehensive, but issues leading to its failure can stem from several areas. Below are the potential problems and their fixes:

Hey, thanks for giving me an insight, but you left out the problems/fixes.
